# Find nCr mod M where M is not prime

Tags: combinations, modulo, inverse

I have to find <sup>n</sup>**C**<sub>r</sub>mod M where M is not a prime number. How can find that. I know that i need to find the inverse modulo but how it is going to be implemented if the number M is non-prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it by the memoization  nCr = (n-1)Cr + (n-1)C(r-1) for M<=5000.
You can visit the link for more info 
        http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m